# Does logging in a Java based web application slow the server?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am working on a java j2ee based web application. When i take some pages, they are loading very slowly. I noticed a lot of unnecessary lines in log file...

Does logging in a java based web application slow the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in any environement, I/O (here, disk writings) is expensive operation, so yes, spamming tons of data into logs, can slow down your applcation. However it has to indeed be a lot of data (eg. turn on `show_sql` in `Hibernate`) to actually feel the performance impact dring normal application usage.